# Issues registering an ActiveX control

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I have some C++ code that I am using a wrapper written in C# so I can use it as an ActiveX control.  So I am using regasm to register the control.  It works for a good portion of my customers.  However, there are some who have issues registering it.  I haven't figured out the main root of the issue because some people have Net3 (Net Framework 3), and Net4 installed, others may only have Net4 installed.  In some of the case installing Net3 fixes the issue, and in others it does not.  I am using Net Framework 2 as a target in Visual Studios 2017.  This is the error I am getting back after attempting to load it via regasm:

{"message":"Permission denied","description":"Permission denied","number":-2146828218}

Comment: Obvious thing to ask upon seeing "Permission denied" in an error message: are you running it as Administrator?

Comment: @GovindParmar the user is in the administrator's group, and registering it manual it registers and runs fine.  However, when we let the app register it, this error occurs.  I believe we on running the application attempt to elevate it, could this be an issue?

Comment: Use this tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon Launch, setup filter to only include regasm.exe, reproduce the error, and search for access denied status. This will tell you which file it tried to access that was denied.